# How do I write nested AND and OR blocks in a hibernate criteria with grails createCriteria

Tags: hibernate, grails, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I tried to write the following SQL-Statement as a criteria:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE (a=1 AND b=1) OR (a=2 AND b=2) OR (a=3 AND b=4)

def textOrderCriteria = TextOrder.createCriteria()
textOrders = textOrderCriteria.list(max: 20, offset: 0) {
  or {
    and {
      eq('a',1)
      eq('b',1)
    }
    and {
      eq('a',2)
      eq('b',2)
    }
    and {
      eq('a',3)
      eq('b',4)
    }
  }
}
```

but that breaks totalCount and the result is not corect because more than one AND per OR is not allowed!

The result is (for my data):

```
textOrders.size() == 6
textOrders.totalCount == 2
```

The result should be (for my data):

```
textOrders.size() == textOrders.totalCount
```

Any ideas to fix this or to work around? How could it be that the size of the result is bigger than totalCount?
I added a jira issue for this: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-7783

Comment: Skurt, could you provide more information on what exactly is going wrong? On a local test the criteria query and the max + offset settings seem to work correctly on Grails 1.3.7 .

Comment: I added more info, hopefully this helps to find the problem

Comment: criteria switches AND and OR
`code`
where
        this_.tenant_id=? 
        and (
            (
                this_.status=? 
                and this_.type=?
            ) 
            or (
                this_.status=? 
                and this_.type=?
            ) 
            or (
                this_.type=? 
                and this_.assigned_to_id=?
            ) 
            or (
                this_.type=? 
                and this_.status=? 
                and this_.project_id in (
                    ?, ?, ?, ?, ?
                )
            )
        ) limit ?
`code`

Comment: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-7783?focusedCommentId=65774&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-65774

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't post this as a comment (not allowed yet!) but you could try setting the

```
loggingSql = true
```

flag in the datasource block of your config.groovy and posting or checking the SQL hibernate is generating? This might give you a clue as to what's going on.

Thanks,

Jim.

Comment: thanks, I know what is going wrong. It is not possible to create this kind of boolean restrictions with the "simple" criteriaBuilder. What I am looking for is the solution to build it on another way.